# nodejs' request module doesn't give response in chunks

Tags: node.js, request, browserify, node-modules, chunks

I have one requirement to download the file from the server using nodejs.

Below is my code to download the file.

**test.js**

```
function downloadFile() {

    var fsModule = 'fs';
    var fs      = require(fsModule);
    var request = require('request');
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var downloadRequest = request.get({
          encoding: null,
          url: 'https://test.com/api/assets/35007/raw',
          headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Basic AuthorizationValue'
          }
    });

    downloadRequest.addListener('response', function (response) {

        if (response.statusCode != 200)  {
            console.log('Error in downloading file');
            deferred.resolve(false);
        } else {
            var options = {defaultEncoding: 'binary'};
            var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('c:/testDownloadFile.mp4', options);

            response.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('chunk length - ',chunk.length);
                writeStream.write(chunk);
            });
            response.addListener("end", function() {
                writeStream.end();
                console.log('No error in download and resolved true');
                deferred.resolve(true);
            });
        }
    });
}
downloadFile();
```

I can run successfully this code using node by below command and it gives response in chunks. so there is no memory issue for this code.

> node test.js

but when I run this code in browser using **browserify** then it doesn't give response in chunks. So it creates a problem for big size file.

1. Is there any problem in **browserify** or **request/buffer** module?
2. What should be the root cause for this issue?
3. Could you please provide me the solution or alternate way to download the file in chunks?

**Node Version:** 6.9.2

**browserify:** ^12.0.0

Answer (score -1):

Just a brief suggestion what what it's worth... In your testing environment did you have any modules held in cache that are not used in when testing in browser. I made this suggestion as there is no require for the q module.

Regards